# Switching from Cycles to Eevee : material turns black

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I searched for a while for a solution but in vain :( I've got a collada object import in Blender with a unique texture. When I make a render with Cycles everything's fine ! But when I want to make a render with Eevee, the texture becomes black... I verified the UV map, I tried to reaffect the material nodes, but the issue is still here.
Thanks for your help !

You can find the file here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qeSegPYoMHfd_D6ln8uKHqqAgWhrtOLB/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you pack the texture in the blender file ? I don't have it so i cannot try out some stuff on my own

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot this. Here's the link updated with the correct file. I updated the first post too. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qeSegPYoMHfd_D6ln8uKHqqAgWhrtOLB/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire model, as imported, consists of 2 layers of faces. (Presumably the importer's interpretation of double-sided faces.) The 'outer' layer is backfacing. It can be hidden by switching on 'Backface Culling' in EEVEE.

It would be safe, (having made a copy) to select any face on the model, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> select linked, and <kbd>X</kbd> delete the lot, leaving behind the correctly oriented faces. If you somehow managed to select the wrong shell, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > Flip, turn the remainder inside-out.

Steps to finding the problem in this case:

- Switch on 'Face orientation' and 'Face Normal' overlays
- Note the normals show outward-facing, but the orientation doesn't.. Eh?
- <kbd>H</kbd> hide a face .. there's another one underneath

Comment: Robin Betts THANK YOU VERY MUCH !! Works perfectly. I'll be careful now about importing objects from other softwares ! Thanks again for taking time to help me !!

Comment: @Helicool It's good to become familiar with the diagnostic overlays, for your own models, as well as other people's :)